# Regex to match characters after the last colon that is not within curly brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regex that matches (and lists) all 'modifiers' of a string. Modifiers are individual letters behind the last `:` in the string. Modifiers can have variables which would be written in curly brackets, e.g. `a{variable}`. Variables may contain the character `:` -- which makes it a bit tricky, because we must look for the last `:` that is NOT between `{` and `}`. This is currently my biggest problem, see Example 6 below.

(If it matters, the target language for this will be javascript.)

I got this working already for the most cases, but got a few edge cases that I can not get to work.

My regex so far is:

```
/(?!.*:)([a-z](\{.*?\})*)/g
```

**Example 1: Single modifier**

`something:a` should match `a` - working fine

**Example 2: Multiple modifiers**

`something:abc` should match `a`, `b`, and `c` - working fine

**Example 3: Single modifier with variable**

`something:a{something}` should match `a{something}` - working fine

**Example 4: Single modifier with multiple variables**

`something:a{something}{something}` should match `a{something}{something}` - working fine

**Example 5: Multiple modifiers with variables**

`something:ab{something}cd{something}{something}efg` should match `a`, `b{something}`, `c`, `d{something}{something}`, `e`, `f`, `g` - working fine

**Example 6: Variable containing `:`**

`something:a{something:2}` - should match `a{something:2}` - does NOT work. I probably need to modify the negative lookahead somehow to ignore colons in curly brackets, but I couldn't find out how to do that.

**Example 7: String not containing a `:`**

`something` - should match nothing, but matches each letter individually. This may or may not be easy to fix, but my brain currently can't work this out.

Here is a link to test / play around with this regex and the examples: https://regexr.com/6h4h0

If anyone can help me to figure out how to make the regex work for example 6 and 7, I'd be very grateful!

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```js
const regex = /.*:((?:[a-zA-Z](?:{[^{}]*})*)+)$/;
const extract_rx = /[a-zA-Z](?:{[^{}]*})*/g;
const texts = ['something:a','something:abc','something:a{something}','something:a{something}{something}','something:ab{something}cd{something}{something}efg','something:a{something:2}','something:a{something:2}b{something:3}','something'];
for (const text of texts) {
  const m = text.match(regex);
  if (m) {
    const matches = m[1].match(extract_rx);
    console.log(text, '=>', matches);
  } else {
    console.log(text, '=> NO MATCH'); 
  }
}
```

See the [main regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/04g1KS/1). *Details*:

- `.*:` - matches any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible and then a `:` followed with...
- `((?:[a-zA-Z](?:{[^{}]*})*)+)` - Group 1: one or more sequences of

  - `[a-zA-Z]` - an ASCII letter
  - `(?:{[^{}]*})*` - zero or more sequences of a `{`, zero or more chars other than `{` and `}` and then a `}` char
- `$` - end of string.

Once there is a match, Group 1 is parsed again to extract all sequences of a letter and then any zero or more `{...}` substrings right after from it.

Comment: I tried to not use a method with multiple regexes, but possibly it's the safer (and saner) way to go after all. Thank you for your effort :)

Answer (score 1):

What you could do instead is make sure there is a colon somewhere before the matched string with a positive lookbehind.
Essentially switching `(?!.*:)` for `(?<=:.*)`.

[Playground](https://regexr.com/6h4ia)

```js
const regex = /(?<=:.*)([a-z](\{.*?\})*)/g;

const strings = [
  "something:a",
  "something:abc",
  "something:a{something}",
  "something:a{something}{something}",
  "something:ab{something}cd{something}{something}efg",
  "something:a{something:2}",
  "something",
];

for (const string of strings) {
  console.log(string.match(regex));
}
```

Comment: This looks great for examples 6 and 7, but causes a new problem: If the string contains `:` before the modifiers begin, it will match everything after the first `:`. The idea is that it should start matching after the last `:` that is not part of a variable. Try matching this: `something:something:a` - it should only match `a` - but matches `s`, `o`, `m`, `e`, `t`, `h`, `i`, `n`, `g` too

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want:

```
:([a-z\{.*?\}0-9])*
```

I would try longer, but have to go catch a flight.